# How i can use two property on responseJson?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to limit the posts in 12 and show only the featured posts with the post_featured key value is 1

```
componentDidMount() {

   return fetch(ConfigApp.URL+'json/data_posts.php')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         posts: responseJson.filter((elem, index) => { return index < 12 && post_featured == '1' })
       }, function() {
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
 }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem or question? You provided a goal and some code but no problem description regarding that code, or errors. Explain what that code is or isn't doing for you as expected. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `elem.` in your filter, try this:

```
posts: responseJson.filter((elem, index) => { return index < 12 && elem.post_featured == '1' })
```

Comment: Sure thing @bdroid